# How to send table to function as argument?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to send a table to function as argument?

Need something like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(argTable TABLE(
        field1 integer,
        field1 integer,
        etc smallint
))
    RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
```

...
Is it possible btw?

UPD: I'm going to send a temp table to function so I suppose I need table structure declaration in arguments list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) which allows the execution of an arbitrary string.

Comment: thanks. actually it's not that I planned to do. but that solved my problem.

Comment: Actually EXECUTE is the better way. My guess is you wanted to pass the table rows in as values. Where execute is more like a pass by reference approach which doesn't incur the cost of moving a big chunk of data around.